# Importing results from X-ray api updates each test's labels

Tags: nunit, jira-xray

I am using X-Ray API to import NUnit `TestResult.xml` result file to Jira. The scenarios that are being run are present in Jira as `Test (XRay)`. Each NUnit scenario has a tag that matches the Jira test key, there are other tags which are not relevant to the Jira test. When the result is imported, new execution is created and the tests are matched and added to that execution. The problem I am facing is that the Jira tests are updated with new labels (the ones that are present in nunit).

Is it possible to disable editing of labels for tests in Jira and to only have the tests added to the execution as-is and to only have their status changed?

Steps:

1. Run any nunit test containing scenarios that can be matched to Jira tests.
2. Import TestResults.xml using the "rest/raven/1.0/import/execution/nunit/multipart" endpoint.
3. New execution is created with Jira, and existing tests are matched based on their key and added to the execution.
4. Notice that the execution tests in Jira are updated with added labels from the TestResults.xml file and additional labels generated by the test name and any error screenshot names.

My info.json file:

`{ "fields": { "project": { "key": "SB" }, "summary": "Automatic result import from automation run", "issuetype": { "name": "Test Execution" } } }`

Specflow scenario that is executed:

`@Regression @SB_110325 @Web @ResponsiveDesktop Scenario: Favorites for Log in user Given Home page is open And I login successfully`

Updated Jira test after the imported result:
[image]

Notice only `Regression_pack` was the original label.

**Update**: Currently this is not possible. I have reported this to the developers and an improvement task was created.

If other people need this implemented, they can vote for it here: [External link](https://jira.getxray.app/browse/XRAY-3190) so it will be picked up and implemented by the developers.